# KeyListener is irresponsive

Tags: java, animation, graphics, timer, keylistener

I want to make a plane move across the board. 
This should be pretty simple since I"ve done it before
I've setFocusable(true), I've added KeyListener, and I've also requestFocusInWindow()

I don't know what's wrong
When a key is pressed, it won't even enter the KeyPressed method
I tested by trying to print out "hi".

```
    package game;

    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;

    public class GUI{

        /* Author: Carl Zhang
         * Date: 
         * 
         */

        //player's username
        public static String user;

        //classes
        public static GUI gui;
        public static LoginPanel lp;
        public static MenuPanel mp;
        public static GamePanel gp;
        public static HighscorePanel hp;

        public static InstructionPanel ip;

        //dimensions
        private static final int WIDTH = 500;
        private static final int HEIGHT = 500;

        public GUI() {


        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ZCraft");
            frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        //adding JPanels
        lp = new LoginPanel();
        frame.add(lp);

        mp = new MenuPanel();
        frame.add(mp);  

        gp = new GamePanel();
        frame.add(gp);

        ip = new InstructionPanel();
        frame.add(ip);

        hp = new HighscorePanel();
        frame.add(hp);

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }//end constructor GUI() 

    public static int getWidth() {
        return WIDTH;

    }//end getWIDTH()

    public static int getHeight() {
        return HEIGHT;

    }//end getHEIGHT

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        gui = new GUI();

    }//end main

}//end class GUI

        package game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    public static GamePanel gp;

    private boolean up = false;
    private boolean right = false;
    private boolean down = false;
    private boolean left = false;

    private ZCraft player;

    private JButton pause, back;

    public GamePanel(){
        //timer
        Timer timer = new Timer(5, this);

        setSize(GUI.getWidth(), GUI.getHeight());
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(false);

        /*

        pause = new JButton("Pause");
        pause.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        pause.setBounds();
        pause.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        pause.setForeground(Color.RED);
        pause.setOpaque(true);
        pause.setBorderPainted(false);
        pause.addActionListener(this);
        add(pause);

        back = new JButton("Back");
        back.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        back.setBounds();
        back.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        back.setForeground(Color.RED);
        back.setOpaque(true);
        back.setBorderPainted(false);
        back.addActionListener(this);
        add(back);

        */

        start();

        timer.start();

        setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(this);
        requestFocusInWindow();
        //setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        //requestFocus();

    }//end constructor GamePanel()

    public void start() {
        player = new ZCraft(GUI.user);

    }//end start()

    public void update() {
        if(up) {
            player.moveYAxis(true);

        }else {
            player.moveYAxis(false);

        }

        if(right) {
            player.moveXAxis(true);

        }else {
            player.moveXAxis(false);

        }

    }//end update()

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        player.render(g);

    }//end render(Graphics g)

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        render(g);

    }//end paintComponent(Graphics g)

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
        update();
        repaint();

    }//end actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}//end keyTyped(KeyEvent e)

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();

        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            up = true;

        }

        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            right = true;

        }

        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            down = true;

        }

        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            left = true;

        }

        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            //player.shoot();

        }

        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_1) {

        }

    }//end keyPressed(KeyEvent e)

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();

        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            up = false;

        }

        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            right = false;

        }

        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            down = false;

        }

        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            left = false;

        }

        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            //player.shoot();

        }

    }//end keyReleased(KeyEvent e)

}//end class GamePanel
```

I just want to enter the method, I'll change the movement thing later

Comment: Please help! THis is my summative

Comment: No [mcve], why? How can we run and test your code? And how is this different from all the similar questions where we recommend to use Key Bindings?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be ignoring the layout manager used by JFrame. The JFrame's contentPane uses BorderLayout, and when adding multiple components to this, you cover previously added components, and so your GamePanel is not even showing much less having focus.

Best solutions:

- Learn and use the layout managers well
- Use [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), not KeyListeners.
- When asking questions, please post a valid [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your question, a small but complete program that only has necessary code to demonstrate your problem, that we can copy, paste, compile and run without modification, as this would help us to fully understand what you might be doing wrong.

My MCVE to test your code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class GUI {
    public static String user;

    public static GUI gui;
    public static LoginPanel lp;
    public static MenuPanel mp;
    public static GamePanel gp;
    public static HighscorePanel hp;

    public static InstructionPanel ip;
    private static final int WIDTH = 500;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 500;

    public GUI() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ZCraft");
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        lp = new LoginPanel();
        frame.add(lp);

        mp = new MenuPanel();
        frame.add(mp);

        gp = new GamePanel();
        frame.add(gp);

        ip = new InstructionPanel();
        frame.add(ip);

        hp = new HighscorePanel();
        frame.add(hp);

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static int getWidth() {
        return WIDTH;

    }

    public static int getHeight() {
        return HEIGHT;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        gui = new GUI();

    }

}

class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    public static GamePanel gp;

    private boolean up = false;
    private boolean right = false;
    private boolean down = false;
    private boolean left = false;

    private ZCraft player;

    private JButton pause, back;

    public GamePanel() {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("GamePanel")); // !!
        Timer timer = new Timer(5, this);

        setSize(GUI.getWidth(), GUI.getHeight());
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(false);

        start();

        timer.start();

        setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(this);
        requestFocusInWindow();

    }

    public void start() {
        player = new ZCraft(GUI.user);

    }

    public void update() {
        if (up) {
            player.moveYAxis(true);

        } else {
            player.moveYAxis(false);

        }

        if (right) {
            player.moveXAxis(true);

        } else {
            player.moveXAxis(false);

        }

    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        player.render(g);

    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        render(g);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        update();
        repaint();

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("keypressed: " + e);
        int code = e.getKeyCode();

        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            up = true;

        }

        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            right = true;

        }

        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            down = true;

        }

        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            left = true;

        }

        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {

        }

        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_1) {

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();

        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            up = false;

        }

        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            right = false;

        }

        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            down = false;

        }

        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            left = false;

        }

        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {

        }

    }

}

class LoginPanel extends MyJPanel {

}

class MenuPanel extends MyJPanel {

}

class HighscorePanel extends MyJPanel {

}

class InstructionPanel extends MyJPanel {

}

class MyJPanel extends JPanel {
    public MyJPanel() {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(getClass().getSimpleName()));
    }
}

class ZCraft {

    public ZCraft(String user) {
    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {

    }

    public void moveXAxis(boolean b) {

    }

    public void moveYAxis(boolean b) {

    }

}
```

Note that only HighScore JPanel shows.

---

Other unrelated issues:

- You are grossly over-using the static modifier, making it more difficult to test your code and enhance your code.
- You are using `null` layouts, a very dangerous thing to do, one making it difficult to upgrade/update your program.

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GUI2 extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 500;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;    
    private LoginPanel lp = new LoginPanel();
    private MenuPanel mp = new MenuPanel();
    private MyGamePanel gp = new MyGamePanel();
    private HighscorePanel hp= new HighscorePanel();
    private InstructionPanel ip = new InstructionPanel();
    private JPanel[] panels = {lp, mp, gp, hp, ip};
    private DefaultComboBoxModel<String> comboModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
    private JComboBox<String> panelsCombo = new JComboBox<>(comboModel);
    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    private JPanel cardHolderPanel = new JPanel(cardLayout);

    public GUI2() {
        for (JPanel panel : panels) {
            String key = panel.getClass().getSimpleName();
            cardHolderPanel.add(panel, key);
            comboModel.addElement(key);
        }

        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.add(panelsCombo);        

        panelsCombo.setFocusable(false);
        panelsCombo.addActionListener(e -> {
            String selection = (String) panelsCombo.getSelectedItem();
            cardLayout.show(cardHolderPanel, selection);
        });

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(cardHolderPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }


    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        GUI2 mainPanel = new GUI2();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyGamePanel extends MyJPanel {
    public MyGamePanel() {
        setKeyBindings();
    }

    private void setKeyBindings() {
        int condition = WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
        InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(condition);
        ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

        KeyStroke enterStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0);
        String enterStrokeKey = enterStroke.toString();

        inputMap.put(enterStroke, enterStrokeKey);
        actionMap.put(enterStrokeKey, new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Enter pressed");
            }
        });
        intoMap(inputMap, actionMap, Direction.UP, KeyEvent.VK_UP);
        intoMap(inputMap, actionMap, Direction.DOWN, KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
        intoMap(inputMap, actionMap, Direction.LEFT, KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
        intoMap(inputMap, actionMap, Direction.RIGHT, KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
    }

    private void intoMap(InputMap inputMap, ActionMap actionMap, Direction dir, int keyCode) {
        KeyStroke release = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0, true);
        KeyStroke pressed = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0, false);
        inputMap.put(pressed, pressed.toString());
        inputMap.put(release, release.toString());
        actionMap.put(pressed.toString(), new DirectionAction(dir, false));
        actionMap.put(release.toString(), new DirectionAction(dir, true));
    }

    private class DirectionAction extends AbstractAction {
        private Direction dir;
        private boolean onRelease;

        public DirectionAction(Direction dir, boolean onRelease) {
            this.dir = dir;
            this.onRelease = onRelease;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.printf("Direction: %s; On Released: %b%n", dir.toString(), onRelease);
        }
    }
}
```

```
enum Direction {
    UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT
}
```

```
class LoginPanel extends MyJPanel {

}

class MenuPanel extends MyJPanel {

}

class HighscorePanel extends MyJPanel {

}

class InstructionPanel extends MyJPanel {

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyJPanel extends JPanel {
    public MyJPanel() {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(getClass().getSimpleName()));
    }
}

class ZCraft {

    public ZCraft(String user) {
    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {

    }

    public void moveXAxis(boolean b) {

    }

    public void moveYAxis(boolean b) {

    }

}
```